# Choosing Elements from subsets

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, set-partition

Let $T$ be a subset of $\{1,2,3,....n\}$ and let $A_T$ represent the number of ways of choosing a distinguished element from $T$. Let $B_T$ be the number of ways of choosing a distinguished element in $T$ and then a subset of the remaining elements. If counting a set in two different ways that $B_T=\sum_{S \subseteq T}A_S$. I was asked to figure out a formula for $A_T$ & $B_T$ for any subset of $T$ and then try to prove algebraically. 
I'm confused as to what $B_T$ is, much less the main point of the question.

How would one define the mobius function

For subsets $S$, $T \subseteq \{1,2,...,n\}$, define
    \begin{equation}
    \mu(S,T)= \begin{cases} 
  (-1)^{|T|-|S|} & if  S \subseteq T \\
   0 & otherwise 
   \end{cases}
   \end{equation}
   and show that
   \begin{equation}
\sum_{S\subseteq\{1,2,...n\}} \mu(S,T)= \begin{cases}
1  & if  T = \{\} \\
0  &  otherwise
\end{cases}
   \end{equation}

with the definition what exactly would be an example for $\mu(S,T)$

Comment: 'distinguished' -> 'distinct'?

Comment: Suppose our set is $\{1,2,3\}$.  $B_T$ would count all possible subsets where one of the numbers was colored red (i.e. is distinguished), e.g. $\{\color{red}{1}\},\{\color{red}{1},2\},\{\color{red}{1},3\},\{\color{red}{1},2,3\},\{\color{red}{2}\},\{1,\color{red}{2}\},\{\color{red}{2},3\},\dots$.

Comment: On the other hand, $A_T$ simply is the number of ways of picking a single element from $T$ to color red and not bothering to write any other elements.  Rather than organizing how you count $B_T$ based on what the distinguished element was first and *then* what the subset that accompanies it is, try doing this in a different order.  As for the algebraic approach, remember your [rule of product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product).

Comment: so A would be just a single element eg. {1,2} (both highlighted red) ?\